# How does one execute JavaScript using Tor network without human interaction?

Tags: linux, javascript

I want to load html content through the Tor network and execute JavaScript that comes with the loaded content to load additional content through the Tor network via AJAX or similar techniques. But I can't use the Tor browser for this. This must be done automated by a script that runs on a Linux server without any human interaction. There is no GUI (graphical user interface) installed on the computer.

Is there a application that ...

1. can use the Tor network to connect to the internet
2. can execute JavaScript to load additional content via AJAX or similar techniques
3. runs on a linux server that has no graphical user interface
4. offers an API that can be controlled by a Perl script or any other

?

Answer (score 2):

Any application can connect over Tor if it supports SOCKS, or if it can be properly wrapped using `torsocks` or `usewithtor`. Aside from that, it seems like you just need a headless browser or some other Javascript execution environment, of which there are many.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do that on linux:

- `apt-get install tor`
- download Multi-TOR from here: `https://github.com/jseidl/Multi-TOR`
- run `./multi-tor.sh 10` for 10 socks ports (for example)
- You can use selenium or splinter python (for example) and import socks port
- put the script on a while or for statement as u wish
- good luck

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import stem.process
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from splinter import Browser


proxyIP = "127.0.0.1"
proxyPort = 9051

proxy_settings = {"network.proxy.type":1,
    "network.proxy.ssl": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.ssl_port": proxyPort,
    "network.proxy.socks": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.socks_port": proxyPort,
    "network.proxy.socks_remote_dns": True,
    "network.proxy.ftp": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.ftp_port": proxyPort
}

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = Browser('firefox', profile_preferences=proxy_settings)
browser.visit("http://yourpage url here")
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```